# android: menu item click event from fragment

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment

I have an application with actionbar. And there is menu inflated by the mainactivity. I want to intercept the click event inside the fragment but I don't know how? Can you help me please?
MainActivity

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);
}
```

home.xml

```
        <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
            android:title="@string/menu_refresh"/>
    </menu>
```

And I want to refresh the list in the fragment

Comment: the fragment use ViewPager

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to capture the click on your item, implement

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
```

And then:

> If your activity includes fragments, the system first calls
>   onOptionsItemSelected() for the activity then for each fragment (in
>   the order each fragment was added) until one returns true or all
>   fragments have been called.

You can follow the oficial reference:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

Comment: thanks, it works! I'll create the refresh method but if I have some bug I'll contact you. Thanks

Comment: @mromer, I have implemented `onOptionItemSelected(MenuItem)` method in fragment, but it does not work. This callback is called in activity but not fragment one, even when there is no resource `id` that matches my click event.

Comment: @Israel are you returning false in your method in your activity? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)