# How to refreshing a fragment on MenuitemSelected of its activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-listfragment, fragmenttransaction

I want to refresh the content of the fragment when a user clicks the refresher icon which is in menu action bar.

My application has three fragments on one activity with view pager; I tried to refresh all of them by calling them in `onOptionsItemSelected()` and I performed transactions to them, the application crashes when a user clicks refresh menu.

I read this question, it is likely similar to mine, but I couldn't find an appropriate answer to settle my problem: [android: menu item click event from fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281242/android-menu-item-click-event-from-fragment) I read this article too: but nothing helped me: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus maybe I am not doing it in a right way.

My code of refreshing all three fragments in the activity are here below:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    Fragment sentMsg=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragmentSentMsg");
    Fragment receivedMsg=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragmentReceivedMsg");
    Fragment allMsg=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragmentAllMsg");
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.refresher_id:
            fragmentTransaction.detach(sentMsg).attach(sentMsg).commit();
            fragmentTransaction.detach(receivedMsg).attach(receivedMsg).commit();
            fragmentTransaction.detach(allMsg).attach(allMsg).commit();

            break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

These are the code of a one fragment:

```
public class Page2_sent_msg extends Fragment {

//default constructor
public Page2_sent_msg(){}

@SuppressLint("ResourceType")
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
    final View Page2_sent_msg=inflater.inflate(R.layout.page2_sent_msg,container,false);


 ListView sentMsgListView=(ListView)Page2_sent_msg.findViewById(R.id.sentMsgListview);
 ArrayList<String> sentMsgArrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
 SQLite_database_helper_class myDb=new SQLite_database_helper_class(getContext());
 Cursor result=myDb.getting_sms_from_db();
 if (result.moveToFirst()){
     do {
         if (!result.getString(3).equals("Sent message")){
             continue;
         }else{
             sentMsgArrayList.add("SMS No : "+result.getString(0)+"\n"
                     +"Address : "+result.getString(1)+"\n"
                     +"Date : "+result.getString(2)+"\n"
                     +"Type : "+result.getString(3)+"\n"
                     +"Content : "+"\n________\n\n"+result.getString(4)+"\n");
         }
     }while (result.moveToNext());
 }
 ArrayAdapter<String>sentMsgAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<>(getContext(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,sentMsgArrayList);
 sentMsgListView.setAdapter(sentMsgAdapter);
 sentMsgListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         //this is what will happen when a user clicks one item from the lis view
     }
 });

 Page2_sent_msg.setTag("sentMsg");


return Page2_sent_msg;
}
```

I do really need a help. Kind regards!

Comment: add crash logs here

Comment: can you refresh from within the fragment?

Comment: @SuhaibRoomy I tried it too, I called that `onOptionsItemSelected()` but it didn't work at all: see how I did it in the same fragment: `@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.refresher_id:
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).attach(this).commitNow();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }` those codes are the fragment which is current, but when I click on refresher icon, the refresh doesn't work

Comment: @SuhaibRoomy the crash log? Well, it says "Your application stopped to work"

Comment: i am asking for logs from logcat

Comment: also i meant can you not call a method inside your fragments and put all the code there that is needed to refresh the contents of the fragment rather than detaching and attaching again

Comment: These are the logs msg   `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setNextAnim(int)' on a null object reference`       `at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:775)`    `at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)`    `at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)`

Answer (score 0):

Just write the fragment transaction in onclick of refresh button

```
 fragment = new HomeFragment();
        onFrangmentChange(fragment, true, false);
```

onFrangmentChange function will be like this

```
    private void onFrangmentChange(BaseFragment fragment, boolean replace, 
  boolean addBackstack) {
    this.fragment = fragment;

    fm = getFragmentManager();

    ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    if (replace) {
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment, fragment);
    } else {
        ft.add(R.id.fragment, fragment);
    }
    if (addBackstack) {
        ft.addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
    ft.commit();
}
```

Note:BaseFragment is nothing but A fragment which extend Fragment.You can write the common functions like checking network connection,email validation etc.in this  fragment.

Comment: should i put these code in the fragment it self or in its activity?

Comment: write in Activity

Comment: I am going to try, what is this fragment `this.fragment`?

Comment: you have to initialize object of BaseFragment like public static BaseFragment fragment;

Answer (score 0):

Add a method refresh in your fragment like this

```
public void refreshFragment() {
    sentMsgArrayList.clear();
    sentMsgAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    SQLite_database_helper_class myDb=new SQLite_database_helper_class(getContext());
    Cursor result=myDb.getting_sms_from_db();
    if (result.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            if (!result.getString(3).equals("Sent message")){
                 continue;
            }else{
                 sentMsgArrayList.add("SMS No : "+result.getString(0)+"\n"
                 +"Address : "+result.getString(1)+"\n"
                 +"Date : "+result.getString(2)+"\n"
                 +"Type : "+result.getString(3)+"\n"
                 +"Content : "+"\n________\n\n"+result.getString(4)+"\n");
             }
        }while (result.moveToNext());
        sentMsgAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged
   }
```

Then called it once the user taps on refresh

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
Fragment sentMsg=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragmentSentMsg");
Fragment receivedMsg=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragmentReceivedMsg");
Fragment allMsg=getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragmentAllMsg");

switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.refresher_id:
        sentMsg.refreshFragment();
        receivedMsg.refreshFragment();
        allMsg.refreshFragment();
        break;
}

return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

}

Comment: It keeps telling me unfortunately "Your application has stopped"

Comment: you will have to post logcat, its difficult to help without it

Comment: can you post code of one of your fragments, i think it would be better if you can write some refresh code in your fragment and then call that method instead of detaching and attaching your fragments, this will fix your issue

Comment: I updated the question and I added the codes of one fragment